# Is it possible to set different look and feel for different panels within a same frame?

Tags: java, swing

Say, I have 3 panels added to a frame and for the 1st panel i want to set the metal look and feel, for the 2nd panel I want windows look and feel, for the third panel it should be default swing style.

is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

The `javax.swing.UIManager` class, where the [look and feel is set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.LookAndFeel)), is a singleton. Only one can be set at any one time.

However, you can (if you're so inclined) override UI delegates on individual components (see [JComponent.setUI()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setUI(javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI))). Using this method you could probably hack together some components that use UI delegates of alternate look and feels. But in most cases they'll look up the `UIDefaults` set by the "real" look and feel, so at best it's probably going to be a poor approximation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Any references?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible, it's happening to me right now. In my GUI class, I've called

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel")
```

For some reason, the container panel is still Metal, while all other components are Nimbus.

Answer (score 0):

What about loading UIManager.setLookAndFeel in a different classloader?

Wouldn't that work?

I guess if it works, you would need to bridge data between the classloaders. I think Google has written such a bridge.