# Can I set two different look and field on one JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set two different look and feel on one frame.
I have two different panels in that. 
i want to set two different look and feel for both.
Can I do that?
And if yes then how?

Comment: I believe you mean 'look and feel'.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The question is quite vague.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713067/is-it-possible-to-set-different-look-and-feel-for-different-panels-within-a-same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The look and feel is a (application) global setting. You can't individually combine different ones. How to set the look and feel is described [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic).

Answer (score 2):

i think Not possible from Java look and feel classes as they are set for whole application like UIManager.setLookAndFeel();

so you have to do it from your own.

Answer (score 2):

A components LAF is determined when the component is created. So theoretically you can do:

a) set LAF
b) create the component
c) reset the LAF to the default.

You may or may not encounter problems so use at your own risk.