# How to change the Look and Feel of a JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, jdesktoppane

I set the LAF of my project to the System default look and feel. Now I'm trying to put a JDesktopPane inside one of my panels but I want all my internal frames to use the java default LAF. Is there a way to change it without changing the LAF of the whole project?

Comment: possibly a dupplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713067/is-it-possible-to-set-different-look-and-feel-for-different-panels-within-a-same

Comment: can someone please give me an answer for this. how do I use the .setUI() method?

Comment: It is mentioned at the top of the [`UIManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) documentation 'update component tree'.  There are a number of quirks (bugs) with mixing PLAFs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.DesktopPaneUI;

public class AddingInternalFramestoaJDesktopPane {
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    desktop.setUI(new DesktopPaneUI() {
    @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.installUI(c);
        }   
    });
    JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Can Do All", true, true, true, true);
    desktop.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 100);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(internalFrame.getTitle(), JLabel.CENTER);
    internalFrame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmJnX.png)
`deks.setUI(new DesktopPaneUI() {
    @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.installUI(c);
        }

    });`

> and with this some file needs to include

`import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;`
`import javax.swing.UIManager;`
`import javax.swing.plaf.DesktopPaneUI;`

> its important

`JDesktopPane deks=new JDesktopPane();`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing a quality answer.