# Applying NimbusLookandFeel only to jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

I have swing application where i just want to use the nimbuslookandfeel for my combobox only not for other components. Is it possible ?

Comment: Not as designed for; you might try it (when not using the System look-and-feel), before and after creating a combobox switching the look and feel, but I would just try to customize the JComboBox, which is doable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set different look and feel for different panels within a same frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713067/is-it-possible-to-set-different-look-and-feel-for-different-panels-within-a-same)

Comment: Actually the intent is i have customized most of the swing components for my application but i want to use some of the nimbus's. So i am trying to find out a way where i can selectively pick them for components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the look and feel of a single part of a java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872492/how-to-change-the-look-and-feel-of-a-single-part-of-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I am able to do it by your suggestions. I restored the default window look and feel after initializing my jcombobox thereby nimbus was only applied to combo.

Thanks again for the help